# How can I insert a row or column into a grouped amount of cells vs the entire sheet?

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I need to know how to create a spread sheet that I can input data like adding a row in a certain group of cells without the row being placed throughout the whole sheet. When grouping rows and columns when I go to in out new data i.e. a new student and info it changes the entire sheet instead of just the group of cells that I am focusing on.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script and the current issue of your script, and the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.